# Apache2 fcgid (not FastCGI) with PHP FPM

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm

Apache2 has a built in fastcgi replacement, called fcgid. That's fine, but it lacks the FastCgiExternalServer directive, which I used to connect to the PHP-FPM. How can I do the same with the fcgid module in apache2?

My goal is to use php-fpm with apache2 (on debian squeeze).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not possible to use an externally spawned FastCGI-aware process like the ones created by `php-fpm` with mod_fcgid. It simply lacks this feature.

If you don't want to use [mod_fastcgi](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/25), i.e. because you think it's too big or insecure or old, you might want to look at an alternative like [mod_proxy_fcgi](http://mproxyfcgi.sourceforge.net/).

You might also be delighted to hear that Apache httpd 2.4 (and the current developer release in the 2.3 series) already comes with a mod_proxy implementation for FastCGI, incidentally also called [mod_proxy_fcgi](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html).

Comment: Does mod_proxy_fcgi play well with APC, as far as you know?

Comment: APC shouldn't "know" anything about `mod_proxy_fcgi` (or `mod_fastcgi` for that matter). I don't know for sure if both play well together but I'd be surprised if they didn't.

Answer (score 2):

mod_fastcgi and mod_fcgid are totally different modules and don't even share a common code-base. They have only the FastCGI protocol in common. That is why Apache Directives are totally different in these two. Besides, mod_fcgid has an adaptive-spawning architecture and it does not support Static servers or External servers. As per my knowledge, it is not possible. But you can check out the latest release and read its change logs.